# Node.js - Parse simple JSON object and access keys and values

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, object, asynchronous

I am new to Node and struggling to access a simple JSON object. My request.body will have JSON content similar to the following:

```
{
    "store_config": [
        {
            "name": "hello",
            "name2": "world"
        }
    ]
}
```

The "store_config" value will always be present, however the keys and values within could be anything.

How can I iterate through the keys and values to access each? I would also like to process each in an asynchronous manner.

Appreciate any thoughts or direction.

---

UPDATE

```
console.log(typeof(request.body));
```

Returns: `Object`

```
parsedBody = JSON.parse(request.body);
```

returns:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
    at Object.parse (native)
```

---

UPDATE 2 - Further debug:

When I try to iterate through the array, there is only a single value:

```
request.body.store_config.forEach(function(item, index) {
  console.log(index);
  console.log(request.body.store_config[index]);

});
```

returns:

```
0
{ name: 'hello', name2: 'world' }
```

Comment: *"I would also like to process each in an asynchronous manner."* Uhm... why?

Comment: FYI, node runs in single thread, so the asynchronous is not the same as in multi-threading programming. When you make a async call with native async procedure like fs.*, it will register a event handler to the event-loop to wait for job to be done. In other cases, you just register a event handler to process.nextTick event, which will callback at each tick, and your code run in series not parallel.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If `request.body` is already being parsed as JSON, you can just access the data as a JavaScript object; for example,

```
request.body.store_config
```

Otherwise, you'll need to parse it with `JSON.parse`:

```
parsedBody = JSON.parse(request.body);
```

Since `store_config` is an array, you can iterate over it:

```
request.body.store_config.forEach(function(item, index) {
  // `item` is the next item in the array
  // `index` is the numeric position in the array, e.g. `array[index] == item`
});
```

If you need to do asynchronous processing on each item in the array, and need to know when it's done, I recommend you take a look at an async helper library [like async](https://github.com/caolan/async)--in particular, [`async.forEach` may be useful for you](https://github.com/caolan/async#forEach):

```
async.forEach(request.body.store_config, function(item, callback) {
  someAsyncFunction(item, callback);
}, function(err){
  // if any of the async callbacks produced an error, err would equal that error
});
```

I talk a little bit about asynchronous processing with the `async` library [in this screencast](http://nodecasts.net/episodes/5-thinking-asynchronously).

Comment: This only applies when using connect/express with bodyParser.

Comment: @brandon-tilley Many thanks. How can I confirm if my request.body is being parsed as JSON already?

If I output the store_config, it is an object:

`console.log(typeof(request.body.store_config));
console.log(request.body.store_config);`

`object`

`[ { name: 'hello', name2: 'world' } ]`

Comment: If it's "object," then it has been parsed--parsing turns a string into an object. (If it was a string, trying to do `request.body.store_config` would give an error.)

Comment: When I try to iterate through the array, there is only a single value:

`request.body.store_config.forEach(function(item, index) {
  console.log(index);
  console.log(request.body.store_config[index]);
  
});`

returns - `0
{ name: 'hello', name2: 'world' }`

Comment: @Ben: That seems correct, as you have one item in your example -- one object with the two properties `name` and `name2`.

Comment: Indeed. If you want to iterate over the object, check out the answer by @DamonGant (minuse the `JSON.parse` part).

Comment: Ah got it! Thanks so much all, really helpful. cc linus-g-thiel @brandon-tilley

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
config = JSON.parse(jsonString);
for(var i = 0; i < config.store_config.length; ++i) {
   for(key in config.store_config[i]) {
      yourAsyncFunction.call(this, key, config.store_config[i][key]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To convert this sting to an actual object, use `JSON.parse`. You can iterate though Javascript objects like you would with an array.

```
config = JSON.parse(string).store_config[0]
foreach (var key in config) {
    value = config[key]
}
```